# Javascript Angular 6 change security through browser dev tools

Tags: javascript, angular, security

Good afternoon in my timezone

I am new to SPA and i am learning Angular.
I am in the Route Guards chapters.
My question is :
 How can we prevent the users from change the code through the browser Dev tools for instance ? In the back end , the code is in the server machine, but in this applications , the code is sent open to the client machine.
If this is not possible to prevent why should we used it ?
If there is some blogs or book regarding this subject it be very appreciated

Thanks in advance
Best Regards

Comment: It is not possible, no. That is one of the downsides of client side applications. You can obfuscate the code to make it harder to read, but you can't outright prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, but your (let's say admin page) which is guarded, enables the user to access some APIs in the backend, now those APIs should require authorization on the server, using tokens or however you implemented your authentication. 
So that only valid users (in this case admins) can use that API.

So if the user is hacky enough, he will be able to access that page on the frontend, however all API calls will be denied by your backend.